# Embedding of the cotangent of the n sphere in R^2n

Tags: differential-topology

It is true that $T^* S^1$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the cotangent of $S^1$ is trivial and $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ is diffeomorphic to the punctured plane. Is it true in general that $T^* S^n$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false for $n = 2$. If $T^\ast S^2$ could be embedded in $\Bbb R^4$, then we would also have an embedding of the unit cotangent bundle $ST^\ast S^2 \cong \Bbb R P^3$ in $\Bbb R^4$. But it is known that $\Bbb R P^3$ does not embed in $\Bbb R^4$ (see for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/96583/21375)).